# Appcelerator, play a sound in Android run, but not in IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, audio, appcelerator

i have the next code

```
var AlarmaIntrusion = Ti.Media.createSound({url:"/alarintru.wav"});
AlarmaIntrusion.play();
```

I'm working with javascript in Appcelerator, with Titanium SDK 5.3.0. Then the code runs fine in Android, but in IOS don´t sound.

Where can be the problem?

Comment: Did you test on device ?

Comment: I play the alarintru.wav in the iphone directly. And play ok. There is any permissions in the app for IOS??

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `/` and ensure to index it from the correct path relative to your working path.